# How can I check all children when parent node checked in Extjs checkcolumn?

Tags: extjs

**My Extjs checkcolumn view**

[image]

**My code snippet**

```
            columns: [{
                xtype: 'treecolumn',
                header: 'Name'
            }, {
                xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                header: 'Check',

                listeners: {
                    checkchange: function(node, checked, eOpts) {
                        // console.warn(JR.app.globalObj.treeNodeSet);
                        console.info(node);
                    }
                }
            }]
```

**In checkcolumn listeners**

```
listeners: {
    checkchange: function(node, checked, eOpts) {
        console.info(node);
        // NO IDEA which node was checked
    }
}
```

No idea which node was checked, How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the grid's checkchange listener onto the column. Either you use `checkchange:function(column, rowIndex, checked, eOpts)` on the column and then get the record via the rowIndex, or you put the `checkchange: function(node, checked, eOpts)` listener on the grid, not the column. (Note that this does fire for every checkchange in every checkcolumn).

Comment: I get rowIndex from checkchange event (it is a number), but how can I find their relationship from the rowIndex? (which one is parent node and which one is child)

Comment: I am not completely sure, but `Ext.data.TreeModel` has a [`query(selector)`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeModel-method-query) method, so I guess `record.query()` will give you all descendants.